# Multiple filter on array of object with onChange in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I need help in filtering the array with more than on filter.i.e i want it to be filter with portName, duration etc.
so if i type portName it should filter the array and then if i type duration it should filter in the filtered array.here is my code, its working when i filter by date and duaration but if i change the date it not effect it.
help me to improve it or suggest me a code by yourself

```
 const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    ship: "",
    departureDate: "",
    duration: "",
    port: "",
  });
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let newFilteredData;

    if (filter.port) {
      if (filterData) {
        newFilteredData = filterData.filter((item) =>
          item.itinerary[0].toString().includes(filter.port)
        );
      } else {
        newFilteredData = data.filter((item) =>
          item.itinerary[0].toString().includes(filter.port)
        );
      }
      setFilterData([...newFilteredData]);
    }

    if (filter.departureDate) {
      if (filterData) {
        console.log(filterData);
        console.log(filterData[0].departureDate);
        console.log(filter.departureDate);
        newFilteredData = filterData.filter(
          (item) => item.departureDate == filter.departureDate
        );
      } else {
        newFilteredData = data.filter(
          (item) => item.departureDate === filter.departureDate
        );
      }
      setFilterData([...newFilteredData]);
    }

    if (filter.duration) {
      if (filterData) {
        newFilteredData = filterData.filter(
          (item) => item.duration == filter.duration
        );
      } else {
        newFilteredData = data.filter(
          (item) => item.duration == filter.duration
        );
      }
      setFilterData([...newFilteredData]);
    }
    if (filter.ship) {
      if (filterData) {
        newFilteredData = filterData.filter((item) =>
          item.ship.name.includes(filter.ship)
        );
      } else {
        newFilteredData = data.filter((item) =>
          item.ship.name.includes(filter.ship)
        );
      }
      setFilterData([...newFilteredData]);
    }
  }, [filter]);
```

it should work with all the filter option, when date then filter by date then duration it filter by date and duration.
but if i change after these two this should filter whole array again

Comment: How are you filtering, your `filterData` state variable is empty

Comment: i have this condition when there is already filtered and i want an other on that

Comment: `
let newFilteredData;
    if (filter.departureDate) {
      newFilteredData = data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item.departureDate == filter.departureDate ||
          item.duration == filter.duration
      );
      console.log(newFilteredData);
      setFilterData([...newFilteredData]);
    }
`


this is the simplest code. but its not working when i want two or more at a time